# What is best way to wrap blocking Try[T] in Future[T] in Scala?

Tags: scala

Here is the problem, I have a library which has a blocking method return Try[T]. But since it's a blocking one, I would like to make it non-blocking using Future[T]. In the future block, I also would like to compute something that's depend on the origin blocking method's return value.

But if I use something like below, then my `nonBlocking` will return Future[Try[T]] which is less convince since Future[T] could represent Failure[U] already, I would rather prefer propagate the exception to Future[T] is self.

```
def blockMethod(x: Int): Try[Int] = Try { 
  // Some long operation to get an Int from network or IO
  throw new Exception("Network Exception") }
}

def nonBlocking(x: Int): Future[Try[Int]] = future {
  blockMethod(x).map(_ * 2)
}
```

Here is what I tried, I just use `.get` method in `future {}` block, but I'm not sure if this is the best way to do that.

```
def blockMethod(x: Int): Try[Int] = Try { 
  // Some long operation to get an Int from network or IO
  throw new Exception("Network Exception") }
}

def nonBlocking(x: Int): Future[Int] = future {
  blockMethod(x).get * 2
}
```

Is this correct way to do that? Or there is a more scala idiomatic way to convert t Try[T] to Future[T]?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's an example that doesn't block, note that you probably want to use your own execution context and not scala's global context:

```
import scala.util._
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object Main extends App {

  def blockMethod(x: Int): Try[Int] = Try {
    // Some long operation to get an Int from network or IO
    Thread.sleep(10000)
    100
  }

  def tryToFuture[A](t: => Try[A]): Future[A] = {
    future {
      t
    }.flatMap {
      case Success(s) => Future.successful(s)
      case Failure(fail) => Future.failed(fail)
    }
  }

  // Initiate long operation
  val f = tryToFuture(blockMethod(1))

  println("Waiting... 10 seconds to complete")

  // Should return before 20 seconds...
  val res = Await.result(f, 20 seconds)

  println(res) // prints 100
}
```

Comment: If you know you're blocking, aren't you supposed to wrap the code in `blocking`?

Comment: Could the `fromTry` method be useful for this? http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.concurrent.Future$

Comment: Self-correcting my previous comment: `fromTry` actually blocks, so no luck there.

Comment: I've run some more experiments and actually `Future(t.get)` doesn't seem to block the thread either. It looks like a simpler solution rather then flatMapping. Thoughts?

Answer (score 8):

In my opinion: Try & Future is a monadic construction and idiomatic way to is monadic composition (for-comprehension):

That you need to define monad transformer for Future[Try[_]] (code for your library):

```
case class FutureT[R](run : Future[Try[R]])(implicit e: ExecutionContext) {
  def map[B](f : R => B): FutureT[B] = FutureT(run map { _ map f })
  def flatMap[B](f : R => FutureT[B]): FutureT[B] = {
    val p = Promise[Try[B]]()
    run onComplete {
      case Failure(e)           => p failure e
      case Success(Failure(e))  => p failure e
      case Success(Success(v))  => f(v).run onComplete {
        case Failure(e)         => p failure e
        case Success(s)         => p success s
      }
    }
    FutureT(p.future)
  }
}

object FutureT {
  def futureTry[R](run : => Try[R])(implicit e: ExecutionContext) = 
    new FutureT(future { run })

  implicit def toFutureT[R](run : Future[Try[R]]) = FutureT(run)
  implicit def fromFutureT[R](futureT : FutureT[R]) = futureT.run
}
```

and usage example:

```
def blockMethod(x: Int): Try[Int] = Try {
  Thread.sleep(5000)
  if(x < 10) throw new IllegalArgumentException
  else x + 1
} 

import FutureT._  

// idiomatic way :)
val async = for {
  x <- futureTry { blockMethod(15) }
  y <- futureTry { blockMethod(25) }            
} yield (x + y) * 2  // possible due to using modan transformer  

println("Waiting... 10 seconds to complete")

val res = Await.result(async, 20 seconds)
println(res)

// example with Exception 
val asyncWithError = for {
  x <- futureTry { blockMethod(5) }
  y <- futureTry { blockMethod(25) }            
} yield (x + y) * 2  // possible due to using modan transformer  

// Can't use Await because will get exception 
// when extract value from FutureT(Failure(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException))
// no difference between Failure produced by Future or Try
asyncWithError onComplete {
  case Failure(e) => println(s"Got exception: $e.msg")
  case Success(res) => println(res)
}
// Output:
// Got exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException.msg
```

Comment: there is a bug somewhere. changing `blockMethod(15)` by `blockMethod(5)` results in an exception that terminates the program, and the last line `println(res)` is not executed.

Comment: Thank you David, I missed description for Exception behaviour, update my answer with Exception example.